# Searching by licence on soundcoud returns 503 error

Tags: soundcloud

When I try to replicate the search by licence, as described here

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#search

with this code

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: //insert client ID here
});

// find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'buskers', license: 'cc-by-sa' }, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
</script>
```

all I get is 503 error. You can try it yourself here

http://karelbilek.com/musicalibre/

It is most probably an issue with SoundCloud since when I remove the `license: 'cc-by-sa'` part, it works fine. Even when I write `licence` instead of `license`, it works fine, but it doesn't filter anything.

I tried to contact SoundCloud by e-mail, but since they don't reply on mail but do reply on questions on SO, I am unfortunately using SO as for reporting bugs.

I will also add that I tried this 7 days ago and it returned the exactly same error, so it's not just a temporary thing.

Comment: Hey Karel, thanks for reporting this, we are looking into it.

Comment: OK :) sorry if I look nitpicky or something, I just didn't get any confirmation from you the first time on e-mail and you don't have any public bugreporting system

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you didn't get a reply, this usually isn't the case. We still think that StackOverflow isn't a bad place to provide support. It seems like it's a bug on our side and I'll post an answer as soon as it gets resolved (shouldn't be long time from now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, the bug is now fixed and deployed. Here's working example of your code: http://jsbin.com/ewamay/1/edit

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to build (well, "hack together" is a better term) a pseudo-radio player just with CC-licensed contents. I now can :)